# Store an image in local application folder in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, image

In my AngularJS application I need to store the images that a user choose from his device, in the application folder.
Only the device used to choose the image has to see it.
So I will save in the backend only the path of this image.

I tried to search how to move or copy an image in a folder, but I haven't found any solution.
How should I do this?

Comment: Are you trying to persist the image in local browser?

Comment: Yes, I want to store images file inside an application folder